# Converting PFObject (Parse) into JSON in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Is there a way to convert a PFObject from Parse into JSON?  I saved as JSON, but when I try to load I'm getting [AnyObject] back.  Casting to JSON won't work:

```
class func loadPeople() -> [String : Person] {

        var peopleDictionary: [String : Person] = [:]

        let query = PFQuery(className: "userPeeps")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {


            //this only returns the first entry, how do I get them all?

            if let peopleFromParse = objects?.first?.objectForKey("userPeeps") as? JSON {
                for name in peopleFromParse.keys {
                    if let personJSON = peopleFromParse[name] as? JSON,

                        let person = Person(json: personJSON) {
                            peopleDictionary[name] = person
                    }
                }
            }
```

below is my save function, which works and saves the JSON into Parse like I want:

```
class DataManager {

    typealias JSON = [String: AnyObject]

    class func savePeople(people: [String : Person]) {

        var peopleDictionary = people

        var peopleJSON: JSON = [:]

        for name in peopleDictionary.keys {
            peopleJSON[name] = peopleDictionary[name]!.toJSON()
        }

        let userPeeps = PFObject(className: "userPeeps")

          userPeeps.setObject(peopleJSON, forKey: "userPeeps")

        userPeeps.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded, error) -> Void in
                        if succeeded {
                            println("Object Uploaded")
                        } else {
                            println("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")
                        }
                    }

    }
```

Comment: You have a couple of problems. First, your objectID won't be "userpeeps" - the id is assigned randomly when a new object is saved to Parse. Second, your JSON string is being saved to the field "userPeeps" inside your PFObject, so you will need to retrieve the string value and convert it to a JSON object - you can't just cast it.

Comment: Thanks I updated my question...i can't figure out how to get all values out though?  this just returns the first

Comment: `objects` is an array of PFObjects. You need to loop through the array.

Comment: Thanks what I was thinking...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer (as Paulw11 points out above) is that "objects" is sort of a wrapper for the real data, so it was necessary to iterate through the array and store each value as JSON:

```
var peopleDictionary: [String : Person] = [:]

        //1 load the dictionary of JSON for key people from Parse
        let query = PFQuery(className: "userPeeps")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                if let unwrappedObjects = objects {

                    for object in unwrappedObjects {

                        if let peopleFromParse = object as? JSON {

                            for name in peopleFromParse.keys {
                                if let personJSON = peopleFromParse[name] as? JSON,

                                    let person = Person(json: personJSON) {
                                        peopleDictionary[name] = person
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```