# Cannot convert value of type "PFUser?" to type "[NSObject : AnyObject]

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pubnub

I'm not sure how to convert a `PFUser` to `[NSObject : AnyObject]` which I think is an `NSDictionary` if I am not mistaken?

Here is the code I am using but I get an error on the last line. I'm quite new to Swift so still trying to figure all this typecasting stuff out.

```
@IBAction func joinLobby(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
        let channel = currentUser["language"] as! String
        self.appDelegate.client?.unsubscribeFromPresenceChannels([channel])
        self.appDelegate.client?.subscribeToChannels([channel], withPresence: true, clientState: PFUser.currentUser() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    }
}
```

Error: "Cannot convert value of type "PFUser?" to type "[NSObject : AnyObject]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is quite self explanatory. There is no way to implicitly convert a PFUser object to a dictionary. You need to construct your own dictionary based on the information you extract from your current user object and send that as the last [argument](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/api-reference#subscribe_args) to subscribeToChannels function.

Also see: [Converting PFObject (Parse) into JSON in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302330/converting-pfobject-parse-into-json-in-swift)

Comment: Thank you for the guidance!